# How to convert xml response using curl into array in php

Tags: php, curl

I am using CURL in my project. When I am sending request, the response is coming in the form of XML as bellow. How can I convert this xml into array to display it in the web page ?

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. 
The document tree is shown below.

```
<Response status="OK" responseTime="10">
<Results>
<wirelineServices>
<blockFIPS>360775908001027</blockFIPS>
<frn>0007556251</frn>
<providerName>Time Warner Cable LLC</providerName>
<doingBusinessAs>Time Warner Cable</doingBusinessAs>
<holdingCompanyNumber>131352</holdingCompanyNumber>
<holdingCompanyName>Time Warner Cable Inc.</holdingCompanyName>
<providerURL>www.timewarnercable.com</providerURL>
<technologies>
<technologyCode>40</technologyCode>
<typicalDownloadSpeed>0</typicalDownloadSpeed>
<typicalUploadSpeed>0</typicalUploadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>9</maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>5</maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>
<overallQuality>1</overallQuality>
<speedQuality>1.00</speedQuality>
<technologyQuality>3.00</technologyQuality>
<providerQuality>3.00</providerQuality>
<downloadQuality>1.00</downloadQuality>
<uploadQuality>1.00</uploadQuality>
<maximumProviderScore>3.00</maximumProviderScore>
<maximumTechnologyScore>3.00</maximumTechnologyScore>
<maximumSpeedScore>2.00</maximumSpeedScore>
<maximumDownloadScore>2.00</maximumDownloadScore>
<maximumUploadScore>2.00</maximumUploadScore>
</technologies>
</wirelineServices>
<wirelineServices>
<blockFIPS>360775908001027</blockFIPS>
<frn>0003469442</frn>
<providerName>Verizon New York Inc.</providerName>
<doingBusinessAs>Verizon New York</doingBusinessAs>
<holdingCompanyNumber>131425</holdingCompanyNumber>
<holdingCompanyName>Verizon Communications Inc.</holdingCompanyName>
<providerURL>www.connecttoverizon.com</providerURL>
<technologies>
<technologyCode>10</technologyCode>
<typicalDownloadSpeed>0</typicalDownloadSpeed>
<typicalUploadSpeed>0</typicalUploadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>5</maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>3</maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>
<overallQuality>1</overallQuality>
<speedQuality>1.00</speedQuality>
<technologyQuality>2.00</technologyQuality>
<providerQuality>2.00</providerQuality>
<downloadQuality>0.00</downloadQuality>
<uploadQuality>1.00</uploadQuality>
<maximumProviderScore>3.00</maximumProviderScore>
<maximumTechnologyScore>2.00</maximumTechnologyScore>
<maximumSpeedScore>2.00</maximumSpeedScore>
<maximumDownloadScore>2.00</maximumDownloadScore>
<maximumUploadScore>2.00</maximumUploadScore>
</technologies>
</wirelineServices>
<broadbandSource>
<stateFips>36</stateFips>
<organization>The New York State Office of Cyber Security</organization>
<organizationURL>http://www.cscic.state.ny.us/broadband/</organizationURL>
</broadbandSource>
</Results>
</Response>
```

The PHP script

```
//Setup cURL Request
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 130);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl); 


$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will work but I'm curious why you're then converting the array that json_decode created into another array? You can display the data on a page just using the [xml object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) returned from simplexml_load_string. You can also display the data from the array output of json_decode. One more thing you can use is [XSLT](http://efxa.org/2013/06/03/how-to-transform-an-xml-document-into-html5-using-xslt/) to add css to your XML as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you, found it on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php). Posted by efredricksen.

```
<?php
class XmlElement {
  var $name;
  var $attributes;
  var $content;
  var $children;
};

function xml_to_object($xml) {
  $parser = xml_parser_create();
  xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
  xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
  xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xml, $tags);
  xml_parser_free($parser);

  $elements = array();  // the currently filling [child] XmlElement array
  $stack = array();
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $index = count($elements);
    if ($tag['type'] == "complete" || $tag['type'] == "open") {
      $elements[$index] = new XmlElement;
      $elements[$index]->name = $tag['tag'];
      $elements[$index]->attributes = $tag['attributes'];
      $elements[$index]->content = $tag['value'];
      if ($tag['type'] == "open") {  // push
        $elements[$index]->children = array();
        $stack[count($stack)] = &$elements;
        $elements = &$elements[$index]->children;
      }
    }
    if ($tag['type'] == "close") {  // pop
      $elements = &$stack[count($stack) - 1];
      unset($stack[count($stack) - 1]);
    }
  }
  return $elements[0];  // the single top-level element
}

// For example:
$xml = '
<Response status="OK" responseTime="10">
<Results>
<wirelineServices>
<blockFIPS>360775908001027</blockFIPS>
<frn>0007556251</frn>
<providerName>Time Warner Cable LLC</providerName>
<doingBusinessAs>Time Warner Cable</doingBusinessAs>
<holdingCompanyNumber>131352</holdingCompanyNumber>
<holdingCompanyName>Time Warner Cable Inc.</holdingCompanyName>
<providerURL>www.timewarnercable.com</providerURL>
<technologies>
<technologyCode>40</technologyCode>
<typicalDownloadSpeed>0</typicalDownloadSpeed>
<typicalUploadSpeed>0</typicalUploadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>9</maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>5</maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>
<overallQuality>1</overallQuality>
<speedQuality>1.00</speedQuality>
<technologyQuality>3.00</technologyQuality>
<providerQuality>3.00</providerQuality>
<downloadQuality>1.00</downloadQuality>
<uploadQuality>1.00</uploadQuality>
<maximumProviderScore>3.00</maximumProviderScore>
<maximumTechnologyScore>3.00</maximumTechnologyScore>
<maximumSpeedScore>2.00</maximumSpeedScore>
<maximumDownloadScore>2.00</maximumDownloadScore>
<maximumUploadScore>2.00</maximumUploadScore>
</technologies>
</wirelineServices>
<wirelineServices>
<blockFIPS>360775908001027</blockFIPS>
<frn>0003469442</frn>
<providerName>Verizon New York Inc.</providerName>
<doingBusinessAs>Verizon New York</doingBusinessAs>
<holdingCompanyNumber>131425</holdingCompanyNumber>
<holdingCompanyName>Verizon Communications Inc.</holdingCompanyName>
<providerURL>www.connecttoverizon.com</providerURL>
<technologies>
<technologyCode>10</technologyCode>
<typicalDownloadSpeed>0</typicalDownloadSpeed>
<typicalUploadSpeed>0</typicalUploadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>5</maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>3</maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>
<overallQuality>1</overallQuality>
<speedQuality>1.00</speedQuality>
<technologyQuality>2.00</technologyQuality>
<providerQuality>2.00</providerQuality>
<downloadQuality>0.00</downloadQuality>
<uploadQuality>1.00</uploadQuality>
<maximumProviderScore>3.00</maximumProviderScore>
<maximumTechnologyScore>2.00</maximumTechnologyScore>
<maximumSpeedScore>2.00</maximumSpeedScore>
<maximumDownloadScore>2.00</maximumDownloadScore>
<maximumUploadScore>2.00</maximumUploadScore>
</technologies>
</wirelineServices>
<broadbandSource>
<stateFips>36</stateFips>
<organization>The New York State Office of Cyber Security</organization>
<organizationURL>http://www.cscic.state.ny.us/broadband/</organizationURL>
</broadbandSource>
</Results>
</Response>
';

echo "<pre>";
@print_r(xml_to_object($xml));
?>
```